# api.patents.stackexchange.com returns a frankensite

Tags: bug, status-completed

In trying to diagnose a userscript bug, I realised that some code was using the old, domain-based API 1.1. Figuring that Patents rightfully had no reason to support the deprecated API, I typed in [the URL](http://api.patents.stackexchange.com) to verify and was surprised to see this:

[image: broken API site]

...instead of a 404 page or the API 1.1 documentation. This seems to only happen for the API subdomain, and requires you to input the broken URL manually, so it's admittedly a very minor issue. All the same, it should probably return something more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, more like [status-half-completed](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-half-completed) really.

The franken site view is gone, but our "no site here" stuff (which does it's best to function when literally nothing else on the network does... it's a tad hairy) doesn't quite deal with retired API v1.x endpoints yet.

We'll get a nicer explanation up there next week, this patch will hold for now.